# Javascript namespaces with Razor syntax?

Tags: javascript, razor

I use this "Javascript namespace" pattern a lot in my script snippets embedded within .cshtml files (partial views):

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function (MyNamespace) {
        MyNamespace.PublicFunc1 = function (p1, p2) {
            localFunc1('abc');
            MyNamespace.PublicFunc2(p1, p2, 'abc');
        }

        MyNamespace.PublicFunc2 = function (p1, p2, p3) {
            // ...
        }

        localFunc1(p1) {
            // ...
        }
    }(window.MyNamespace = window.MyNamespace || {}));
</script>
```

It works like a charm and I can call these `MyNamespace.PublicFunc1` and `MyNamespace.PublicFunc2` functions from outside that script snippet.

The problem arises when two or more of those partial views need to be rendered at the same time, so any external JS code making calls to, say, `MyNamespace.PublicFunc1` will no longer be able to do so, because there would be two or more instances of that function.

To solve this, I tried using server-side unique namespace IDs/names for those scripts via Razor syntax, i.e.:

```html
@{
    // server-side variable with a unique namespace identifier/name
    string _namespace = Model.MyUniqueNamespace;
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function (@_namespace) {
        @_namespace.PublicFunc1 = function (p1, p2) {
            @_namespace.PublicFunc2(p1, p2, 'abc');
        }

        @_namespace.PublicFunc2 = function (p1, p2, p3) {
            // ...
        }

        localFunc1(p1) {
          // ...
        }
    }(window.@_namespace = window.@_namespace || {}));
</script>
```

The problem with this approach is that the entire `@_namespace.PublicFunc1` part is treated by Razor and server-side -- which makes sense, but is not what I need; I only need the `@_namespace` part to be server-side and everything else around it to be client-side/JS.

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to solve this using Razor syntax?
2. Is there another/better way to handle these scenarios (via Javascript magic), without having to write a full-fledged JS plugin/widget/library (would seem like too much for each such localized/page-specific script snippet)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing it to `@(_namespace)` should work for question 1. For question 2, it's important to note that the variable name you pass into the function doesn't... really... matter. i.e.:

```
(function(foo) {
  foo.func1 = function() { ... }
})(window.bar = window.bar || {});
```

this will still set `window.bar.func1`.

Comment: It worked, thanks for the quick reply!!  Re. question #2 -- the difference in naming there doesn't help in my case... besides it's better to keep those names the same for consistency/cleanliness.